# Compilation and link of circular dependencies permittted with static libraries?

Tags: c++, linker

The project I was handed seems to compile and link just fine even though there are obviously many circular dependencies between static libraries in the solution.

```
static library "A" constructs a class from static library "B"
static library "B" constructs a class from static library "A"
Executable C constructs classes from "A" and B"
```

I did not think this was possible.
Is it supposed to be? Is so, can someone explain in detail why this works?

When I try to convert "A" and "B" to dynamic libraries, I cannot build either one without link errors.

Comment: Static libraries can depend on each other with Visual Studio. DLLs can not have a circular dependency path.

Comment: Why? I need an in depth explanation of what occurs under the hood that makes this possible, such that I can regurgitate it to my peers.

Comment: Linking is done at the executable not the static library. Which means symbols from one static library need not exist when building another static library. They just have to exist when building the executable.

Comment: Resolving the dependencies for a static library happens later, delayed until the linker starts chewing on it.  You could never build a program that *only* uses A.  Similarly, you can never build a DLL that only uses A, B has to be linked as well.  Modularity out of the window, only easy way is to build one DLL that exposes both libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did not think this was possible.

You were quite mistaken.

> Is so, can someone explain in detail why this works?

Here is one [explanation](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html). Here is [another](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking).

Comment: I think the latter explanation is very nice. I assume the dynamic link library gets put together just like the executable. How it is linked would be a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

It works because linking symbols are not typed. As long as all symbols are resolved in the end, the linking is essentially a success.